# TFS 2013 rest api basic authentication is not working

Tags: rest, api, tfs

I've tried to get the projects from the TFS on-premise version using below API,
**http://tfs2013.ilinktrichy.com:8080/tfs/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0**

Used the basic authentication and enabled the basic authentication in IIS as well. **Still am getting 401 unauthorized issue.**

Do i need to do any other changes on IIS?

Comment: How are you invoking the API? Using a script? From a tool? What do your authentication headers look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy answer, but you're not going to like it.

TFS 2013 did not have REST APIs. They were introduced in TFS 2015.

You can use the old SOAP .NET client for automating tasks against TFS 2013, or (better yet) you can upgrade to a modern version.

*update*

What I said is not entirely accurate: *some* of the APIs were present in 2013, but they were not officially introduced until 2015 and are thus largely undocumented and totally unsupported.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. yes some of the API's are not supported in TFS onpremise.